# filter items in a one to many field using domain in odoo

Tags: python, onchange, odoo-10

I have an `onchange` function which populates products and services in a one to many field I want to filter the items in such a way that only products are populated while services are left out currently my function populates both product types

## on change update lines

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('project_id')
def change_project_id(self):
    # get project id
    project_id = self.project_id.id
    domain = [
        ('project_budget','=',project_id),
        ('state','=','done')
    ]

    # get approved budget
    approved_budget = self.env['project.budget'].search(domain,limit=1)
    data = {}
    #
    new_lines = self.env['custom_stock_requisition.line']
    # loop through budget lines
    for line in approved_budget.budget_line_items:
        ##populate items
        data = {
            'product_id': line.product_id.id,
            'quantity': line.product_qty,
            'product_uom': line.product_uom.id,
            'price_unit': line.price_unit,
            'product_categ_id': line.product_categ_id,
            'name': line.product_id.name,
            'date_planned': datetime.datetime.now()
        }
        new_line = new_lines.new(data)  # adding new items to the model
        new_lines += new_line
    #
    self.requisition_order_line += new_lines  # set requisition order lines
    return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

@api.multi
@api.onchange('project_id')
def change_project_id(self):
    # get project id
    project_id = self.project_id.id
    domain = [
        ('project_budget','=',project_id),
        ('state','=','done')
    ]

```
# get approved budget
approved_budget = self.env['project.budget'].search(domain,limit=1)
data = {}
#
new_lines = self.env['custom_stock_requisition.line']
# loop through budget lines
for line in approved_budget.budget_line_items:
    ##populate items
    if line.product_id.type != 'service:
       data = {
           'product_id': line.product_id.id,
           'quantity': line.product_qty,
           'product_uom': line.product_uom.id,
           'price_unit': line.price_unit,
           'product_categ_id': line.product_categ_id,
           'name': line.product_id.name,
           'date_planned': datetime.datetime.now()
        }
       new_line = new_lines.new(data)  # adding new items to the model
       new_lines += new_line
#
self.requisition_order_line += new_lines  # set requisition order lines
return {}
```

Comment: simply add condition so that services cannot added into your lines